# Shortcut to execute last query in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

Does there exist a shortcut  to execute the last query run in *SQL Server*?

I can see the *Query shortcuts* in the Options menu under *Environment* (SSMS 2008) but nothing listed seems to describe this functionality.

[image: SSMS Shortcuts]

Comment: Do you want to execute last query that YOU have executed via SSMS, or last query executed in SQL Server globally ?

Comment: In SSMS. I'm sure everyone has multiple queries in the one document when in dev mode. I constantly need to re-highlight the desired query and run it when I am switching between windows and documents. Surely there is quicker way. @AndreiRantsevich

Comment: I see.. Well, there is no shortcut for that. I think that it might be a bit dangerous just to repeat last run query, because you could also forget which one it was. I have asked that, because I develop SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS and acctually "collect" user requests like your one. I could imagine that more "safe" way would be to "restore last selection" command. You will know then what query you are going to re-run. On the other way we have already executed queries history. But currently it simply logs executed statements to disk. You might check existing functionality and make your proposal.

Comment: Very true it is dangerous in some instances. But this is no where near a production env. This would be a small nice productivity boost. I could probably create a sp that uses `sp_executesql` to pass in the last query executed my me on the db but would not be that clean. I also like your product, am wishing I brought this instead of SQL Prompt. @AndreiRantsevich

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is simply two letters. "no"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that what you're specifically asking for is possible. However if you are willing to tackle your problem another way. I use a tool every day that might make what you are asking for possible, or at least as close as I think you might get.

[SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/) is a plugin for SQL Server Management Studio that has a number or really great features. One that might interest you is the Current Window History. This is a window with all of the commands that have been run from this tab. While it doesn't do what you originally asked for, I feel like it is at least in the spirit of what you were trying to accomplish.

[image: Current Window History]